# Get tab name in Chrome with Playwright

Tags: python, selenium, playwright

I am trying to fetch the tab name with playwright, but my code only outputs the page url.

For instance, I want to go to https://www.rottentomatoes.com/ and print the name being shown on the tab:

Rotten Tomatoes: Movies/ Tv Shows/ Movie Trailers...

I tried to use page.title and a few other options, but it is not working.

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

website = "https://www.rottentomatoes.com/"


p = sync_playwright().start()
browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
page = browser.new_page()
page.goto(website)
print(page.content)
print(page.inner_text)
print(page.title)
print(page.context)
```

My output is:

```
<bound method Page.content of <Page url='https://www.rottentomatoes.com/'>>
<bound method Page.inner_text of <Page url='https://www.rottentomatoes.com/'>>
<bound method Page.title of <Page url='https://www.rottentomatoes.com/'>>
```

Comment: These are methods, they need to be called with parentheses, like `print(page.title())`. See the "Usage" section of [the docs page](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by other user. You need to pass selector as an arugument in the method `inner_text(Selector)` to get the value.

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

website = "https://www.rottentomatoes.com/"


p = sync_playwright().start()
browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
page = browser.new_page()
page.goto(website)
print(page.inner_text("rt-header-nav[slot='nav-dropdowns'] [slot='movies']  a[slot='link']"))
print(page.inner_text("rt-header-nav[slot='nav-dropdowns'] [slot='tv']  a[slot='link']"))
print(page.inner_text("rt-header-nav[slot='nav-dropdowns'] [slot='trivia']  a[slot='link']"))
```

This will print in the console.

```
MOVIES
TV SHOWS
MOVIE TRIVIA
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the comment by G. Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75249155/get-tab-name-in-chrome-with-playwright#comment132785170_75249155), right now you’re just referencing the method but not calling it, so `page.title` should be `page.title()` as shown in [the page title docs](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-title). Which is why the output was just saying “bound method…”

Hope that helps!